# Webcam image has weird colors and lines over the picture

Tags: 11.10, google-chrome, google-talk, logitech

Does anyone has a clue why the Logitech E3500 camera stream is displayed in some kind of distored or tinted image in GoogleTalk chat ? In both setup window and in the online video chat too.

- google-talk plug-in displays the picture with lines and wrong colors in it, also the resoltuion seems to be different to standard. Is the plugin trying to adjust "wide screen" res. ?
- guvcview can display image correctly with 640x480 resolution
- cheese video is OK as well

Can anyone give a hint what could be the cause please ?

- Ubuntu 11.10 64bit
- Plugin Google Talk verze 2.5.6.0
- Plugin Google Talk - akcelerátor videa verze 0.1.44.14

:~$ uname -a

```
Linux doma-MS-7125 3.0.0-14-generic #23-Ubuntu SMP Mon Nov 21 20:28:43 UTC 2011 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 2):

With the last update of Google Talk plugin (2.6.1.0-1) the issue was solved in my Ubuntu 11.10 64b.
I still waiting for an update for Skype...

Regards.

Daniel.